# TensorFlow Serving: Pass image to classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have built a simple classifier in Tensorflow (Python, tensorflow 1.9.0 and tensorflow-serving 1.9.0) which classifies objects into one of 5 classes. Now, I would like to serve that model. I have exported it and given it a classification signature (and only a classification signature):

```
classification_signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs={signature_constants.CLASSIFY_INPUTS: classification_inputs},
    outputs={
        signature_constants.CLASSIFY_OUTPUT_CLASSES:
            classification_outputs_classes
    },
    method_name=signature_constants.CLASSIFY_METHOD_NAME)
```

which, further down the line, becomes:

```
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            sess, [tag_constants.SERVING],
            signature_def_map={
                'classification_results':
                    classification_signature
            },
            clear_devices=True, legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)
```

And when I start the TF server I can see that the model is being served. My problem is how to pass an image to is from the client. The code is as follows:

```
request = classification_pb2.ClassificationRequest()
request.model_spec.name = model
request.model_spec.signature_name = 'classification_results'
```

And this is where I am sort of lost and somewhat confused. For a PredictionRequest the code is:

```
request.inputs['inputs'].CopyFrom(
    tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(image.astype(dtype=np.uint8), shape=[1, height, width, 3]))
```

but that does not work for a ClassificationRequest. The error is:

```
File "TestServices.py", line 99, in make_request
  request.inputs['inputs'].CopyFrom(
     AttributeError: 'ClassificationRequest' object has no attribute 'inputs'
```

Neither does:

```
request.input.CopyFrom(input_pb2.Input(
    tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(image.astype(dtype=np.uint8), shape=[1, height, width, 3])
    )
)
```

which gives the error:

```
File "TestServices.py", line 102, in make_request
  tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(image.astype(dtype=np.uint8), shape=[1,height, width, 3])
    TypeError: Parameter to CopyFrom() must be instance of same class: 
    expected tensorflow.serving.Input got tensorflow.TensorProto.
```

My question, therefore, is: What do I need to do pass an image to the classifier using a ClassificationRequest?

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: Updated the post. It seems there is some fundamental difference between how things are passed to a prediction and classification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is according to best practices but this seems to work. As a pure python user, I have to say this feels like hocus pocus. I took me a while but I figured it out by looking at the [definition](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/apis/input.proto) of the protobuf files and this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow_serving.apis import classification_pb2, input_pb2
image = np.random.rand(1, 32,32,3)

def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

request = classification_pb2.ClassificationRequest()
request.model_spec.name = 'model'
request.model_spec.signature_name = 'classification_results' 

# Wrap numpy image in an example protobuf
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={'image': _bytes_feature(image.tostring())}))

inp = input_pb2.Input()
inp.example_list.examples.extend([example])

request.input.CopyFrom(inp)
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the above (have seen it a few places) as, like you said, this (to me) is black-box nonsense. But I will give it a go and get back to check the answer.

Comment: I would say it works - mostly. The problem is that the 'bytes' call converts everything to a string, and the model expects floats. Did you find a way to fix that?

Comment: That is specific to how you trained your model. My guess would be to swap `tf.train.BytesList` with a `tf.train.FloatList` and pass `image` instead of `image.tostring()`

Comment: Yea I tried that, but now TF serve is complaining over it is getting string input instead of float. I don't get that, but that doesn't change the fact that your answer helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: I like the `saved_model_cli` to quickly check input and output specs of a saved model. Perhaps you can try it :)

Comment: Did that too :). It clearly shows that it (the model) expect floats. Using a FloatList means first converting it to a flat array (image.flatten().tolist())  and, because a list is not iterable, remove the brackets from [value]. That produces a  long list with a value: <float> for each value in the image. However, the model complains that it is being given a string and not float. I have no idea why.